# Why my loop print every results even though im not using printf

Tags: octave

Why my loop print every results even though im not using printf.
this is my coding. the result is print as matrix for every loop that been executed

```
r1=0.963;
r2=0.764;
r3=0.528;
r4=1.815;
r5=0.778;
phi1=0*(pi/180);
phi2l=0*(pi/180);
phi2u=90*(pi/180);
phi2ro=90*(pi/180);
printf("    phi-1     phi-2     phi-3     x-p     y-p\n");
printf("--------------------------------------------------\n");
do
  phi2r=((phi2l+phi2u)/2); #CALCULATE PHI2R
  fphi2l=((r1*cos(phi1)+r2*cos(phi2l)-r4)^2+(r1*sin(phi1)+r2*sin(phi2l))^2-(r3^2)); #EXECUTE FUNCTION USING PHI2L
  fphi2r=((r1*cos(phi1)+r2*cos(phi2r)-r4)^2+(r1*sin(phi1)+r2*sin(phi2r))^2-(r3^2)); #EXECUTE FUNCTION USING PHI2R
  check=fphi2l*fphi2r; #CALCULATE VALUE FOR CONDITION
  if(check<0)
  {
    phi2u=phi2r;
  }
  endif
  if(check>0)
  {
    phi2l=phi2r;
  }
  endif
  error=abs(phi2r-phi2ro)/phi2r; #CALCULATE ERROR
  phi2ro=phi2r;
until(error<10^-8)
phi2=phi2r;
phi3=asin((r1*sin(phi1)+r2*sin(phi2))/r3);
phi3c=acos((r1*cos(phi1)+r2*cos(phi2)-r4)/r3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax "error" in your if blocks. In octave you don't need to enclose the if "block" in braces. What you're written effectively wraps that assignment inside a 'cell'. And because the 'cell' statement isn't terminated by a semicolon (note that the semicolon is inside the cell!), the resulting cell gets printed on the terminal.

You can just do this instead:

```
if check > 0
  phi2l = phi2r;
endif
```

Comment: thanks, thats really solve my problem.. its because i used to learn c languange, and i like to keep my works looks organised